# Find x so three points form a right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry

Q. Find x so that the points $(x, x + 1), (x + 2, x + 3)$ and $(x + 3, 2x + 4)$ form a right angled triangle.

Clearly, for it to be a right-angled triangle I need to prove that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. So I calculated the three sides (using the distance formula), and assumed I could solve for x. But my calculations failed. Where did I go wrong?

[image: workings 1]

[image: workings 2]

(attempt for $d_1^2 + d_3^2 = d_2^2$ failed to scan, but also did not resolve)

Comment: $(x+1)^2=(x+3)^2 \implies 2x+1 = 6x+9 \implies x=-2$

Comment: Fewer errors to take the differences between point pairs as vectors and see what $x$ values give a pair of vectors orthogonal. Two of your conclusions are correct, $x^2 + 4x + 6 = 0$ gives complex $x$ and $(x+1)^2 = (x+3)^2$ does complete to a correct $x.$ There is another real $x$ that works

Comment: Are you familiar with any vectorial methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need square roots, so
you have

\begin{align} 
d_1^2&=8
,\\
d_2^2&=x^2+2x+2
,\\
d_3^2&=x^2+6x+18
.
\end{align}

One solution is

\begin{align} 
d_1^2+d_2^2-d_3^2
&=8+x^2+2x+2-(x^2+6x+18)
=-4x-8=0
,\\
x&=-2
,
\end{align}

and anothe one is
\begin{align} 
d_1^2-d_2^2+d_3^2
&=8-(x^2+2x+2)+(x^2+6x+18)
=4x+24=0
,\\
x&=-6
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The vectors connecting the three points are $\pmatrix{2 \\ 2}$, $\pmatrix{1 \\ x+1}$, and $\pmatrix{-3 \\ -x-3}$. Since the vectors need to be perpendicular, we need to find when $\hat{u} \cdot \hat{v} = 0$.

In the first case, $2 + 2(x+1) = 0$, which leads to  $x = -2$.

In the second case, $-3 + (x+1)(x-3) = 0$. We then have a quadratic equation: $x^2-2x-6=0$. Completing the square, we have $x^2-2x+1 = 6+1$, so $(x-1)^2 = 7$, and $x = \sqrt{7}+1$ or $-\sqrt{7}+1$.

In the third case, with $\pmatrix{-3 \\ -x-3}$ and $\pmatrix{2 \\ 2}$, $-6 + 2(-x-3) = 0$, so $x=-6$.